# How to determine aerosol model value for i.atcorr in GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis

The `i.atcorr` [module](http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/html_grass70/i.atcorr.html) in GRASS requires aerosol model data to perform [atmospheric correction](http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Atmospheric_correction) using the 6S algorithm.

It seems like I need **a value from one of these parameters** to continue:

- Estimate of the **meteorological parameter visibility** v [km], or
- The **aerosol optical depth (AOD) at 550nm**

**Is there an easy (and free) way to get such data**?

****EDIT (new findings):**

It seems that a NASA website called [Space-Based Measurements of Ozone and Air Quality in the Ultraviolet and Visible](http://ozoneaq.gsfc.nasa.gov/) got the **free aerosol model data**. It is organized by date and by the instruments that collected the data. Basically:

- **OMI (Ozone Monitoring Instrument)** is for data dated July 2004 onward
- **TOMS Earth Probe** is for data dated 7/25/96 - 12/31/05
- **TOMS Nimbus-7** is for data dated 11/1/78 - 5/6/93

I'm processing a Landsat scene dated in year 2000-2001, so Toms Earth Probe data is the way to go. **But as stated by @Tobi in an answer below, TOMS Earth Probe data is actually an index, and unitless** (not really AOD at 550nm which I want in the 6S algorithm).

But I've stumbled upon this called [A Long-Term Record of Aerosol Optical Depth from TOMS Observations and Comparison to AERONET Measurements](http://www.gfdl.noaa.gov/bibliography/related_files/torres0201.pdf), and they *hinted* how the data in TOMS observation can still be used.

I need more time to learn how to do this. Welcome any further input, always..

Comment: Have you consulted the [manual](http://6s.ltdri.org/6S_code2_thiner_stuff/6s_ltdri_org_manual.htm)?

Comment: I have - but I don't think it's there.. I think the values should be time/location specific..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Nasa's Aeronet](http://aeronet.gsfc.nasa.gov/) provides free AOD data from sensors around the world.

Comment: This is nice! If only the data isn't so random.. The data is user-submitted, right?

Comment: @Haziq, did you use NASA's Aeronet data along with i.atcorr?

Comment: Not really. I picked this as answer because it *is* an easy (and free) way to get data. The problem is I can't use them because they didn't exactly match the time/location of my data-set. I've decided to abandon my search (for now) and opted for the simpler DOS1 method.. Sorry that I can't be much of a help..

Comment: See also Moritz Lennert's suggestion (posted in grass-user ML) on using estimations from [Rayleigh-scattering calculations for the terrestrial atmosphere](http://www.opticsinfobase.org/ao/abstract.cfm?uri=ao-34-15-2765)

Comment: Two more, potentially useful, links: http://www.globaerosol.info/project_description/data.htm, http://gacp.giss.nasa.gov/data_sets/

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the link, helped me a lot with my work! Not sure if you have solved the problem already, but here's a quick suggestion.

If you look at the data file, you will find that each value is represented by three characters. The first line is `__1__1__0__7__0999...` and is equal to `001001000007000999...`

So it basically comes down to splitting up the lines in chunks of three and taking the 255th value.

For a single file you can easily do this in a text editor:

1. Each line is indented by 1, so delete one white space at the beginning of each line
2. Replace all whitespaces with zeros
3. Find char no 255*3=765 and use chars 763-765 as your value.

If you are working with many files, use Python or similar to automate the data extraction.

One more thing, feel like I should mention it: The data is just for the UV Aerosol Index, which is different from AOD! You would probably want to use something like the OMAERO products (after 2004) at http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/Aura/data-holdings/OMI

Comment: I see, that's one way to do it.. But I've decided to pursuit this route of atmospheric correction at other time and have opted (for now) the simplified DOS1 method. **Thanks for the clarification of the TOMS Earth Probe data: it is indeed an index and unit-less** - not quite like the AOD data required by the 6S algorithm.. But I have yet to find free AOD data readily usable for the period of Landsat I'm using (<2004). But with further reading [here](http://www.gfdl.noaa.gov/bibliography/related_files/torres0201.pdf), the data *could* still be processed further to develop the model. Maybe.

Comment: Have you checked Giovanni http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/giovanni/overview/index.html and the MODIS AOD data >2000?

Comment: Hey, I was wondering where to get the MODIS AOD data (it's not available on their site).. I'll take a look at this site thoroughly later; so far the data I can see there is in the same form as the TOMS data - Aerosol Index (man, NASA websites sure are complicated to browse through - I got a headache just by looking at it).. Anyway, thank you so much @Tobi :)!

Comment: It's a little hidden -- here's the direct link to their ftp server: ftp://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/allData/51. Look at the MOD08... products (daily to monthly).