# Retrieving Aerosol Optical Depth (AOT) from Landsat multispectral data

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, envi, erdas-imagine, matlab

I need to retrieve Aerosol Optical Depth from Landsat multispectral datasets.

Has anyone successfully tried something like that before?

Comment: This looks like it could be a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40531/how-to-determine-aerosol-model-value-for-i-atcorr-in-grass