# How to determine aerosol model value for i.atcorr in GRASS? (Using Aeronet data)

Tags: grass-gis, atmospheric-correction

I am trying to conduct atmospheric correction of landsat 8 image using i.atcorr of Grass GIS. In thıs regard, I need to know Aerosol Optical Depth (AOD) as stated in Grass wiki page. I've found some valuable leads ın this site and explored Aeronet (http://aeronet.gsfc.nasa.gov/new_web/aerosols.html). I prefer it (relative to MODIS MOD08) since it offers a lot more detail and timeseries of data (I think I just need the data for the time when image was taken). However, the data file for my specific site contains no data at AOT_550 (I presume that is the exact wavelength sought). there is AOT_555 and AOT_551 but without any data. The closest data I found is AOT_500 and AOT_675. Another thing I noticed, the data value gradually decreases from AOT_340 to AOT_1640. My question, Is it possible to use a linearly interpolated value for AOT_550 by using AOT_500 and AOT_675 data?

Comment: The usual practice is, as you suggested, to interpolate between the two values for the two available wavelengths (and for the two entries closest in time to your landsat time)

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40531/how-to-determine-aerosol-model-value-for-i-atcorr-in-grass?rq=1